# backBarButtonItem becomes visible on iOS 10 when titleView has constraints

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, ios10

Having a very weird behavior on iOS 10. Assume you have an empty app, created with a Master-Detail Application template. Place any `UIView` as a titleView in navigationBar for detail viewcontroller. Place any `UIView` to the right bar button items. 
[image: sample configuration screenshot]

Then, write that code to `configureView` method:

```
if let item = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = item
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
}
```

Then configure splitviewcontroller `preferredDisplayMode = .allVisible`, so the `displayModeButtonItem` could appear.

On iOS 9 and lower this results in a standard behavior: the detail viewcontroller displays `displayModeButtonItem` expand button on a left side.

[image: collapsed state]

When user taps it, the icon transforms to an arrow. Tapping an arrow reverses button state.

[image: expanded state]

On iOS 10 `displayModeButtonItem` displays as expand button, but if user taps it, it disappears.

[image: displayModeButtonItem dissapeared]

Meanwhile, the button is still there and a user can tap it one more time. After that, `displayModeButtonItem` appears again with expand icon **and** backButtonItem icon as well. Just like it appears when we push another viewcontroller onto detail's navigationcontroller:

[image: displayModeButtonItem and 2 icons]

But in that case both of icons acts as `displayModeButtonItem`.
Is this an iOS bug, or a misconfig? What can I do to get normal button behavior?

---

Edit: I found out, that everything works as expected, if a titleView (of rightBarButtonItem's view) does not contain any constraints on it's child views. Filed a [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/29374954) on this.

---

Edit 2: Some controls (like UIImageView) may implicitly add `NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint`, so, to prevent this behavior (and prevent the bug above), subclass it and override `intrinsicContentSize` method like this:

```
private class NoConstraintsUIImageView: UIImageView {
    private override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        // prevent implicit NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint adding in updateConstraints
        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric)
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been scratching my head over the same issue. Just setting the titleView to any UIView and then calling setNeedsUpdateConstraints() on that view causes the same issue. Both the back and expand buttons appear.